# Custom skin and flicker

Tags: .net, custom-controls

I created a custom skin with overlaying transparent images and TransparencyKey.

http://jesconsultancy.nl/vb.rar
(Only right bottom corner works to resize)

I have written custom code to resize and drag the application. But when i resize the application it flickers. There wil become some space between the borders of the image/panels. How do I solve this?

I can't make a screenshot of the problem because on the screenshot there is no flicker effect :/

Comment: Can you post the custom skinning code and/or the resizing code from your application? Although you're right about not being able to post a screenshot—I chuckled at that, mostly because I thought about asking for one. Edit: Or, uhh, zip up your *code*, rather than the EXE. I certainly don't want to open some unknown executable on my dev box!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you redrawing on every resize event? If so, you might be redrawing too often, and might need to decouple your render from the resize event (e.g. while resizing and mouse down, don't render). I've had similar problems before, but on dragging objects in a window ...

Comment: Hmm.. Yes it is redrawing on the resize event. I am going to look into that one. Thanks!

Comment: Np good luck with it -- you should be able to just set a flag to skip Painting if you're resizing and the mouse button is down.